# how to read the parent node name without getting value from firebase For ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to read the `restaurant` names `Burger King`, `Eating Point` using swift.

How it can be possible, Can anyone help me please this is for my final project need to submit in 1 week please i'm losing hope with this

[image]

```
 ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref?.child("Restaurants").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let rest = snapshot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = rest {


            self.restList.append(actualPost)

            print("list of rest ", self.restList)


            self.restTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Make a reference of `Restaurants` node and then perform firebase query.

Comment: And what does `without getting value from firebase For ios` mean in your question title?

Comment: i've done this code but it is returning nil value

Comment: Change `.childAdded`  to `.value` type to get the whole value.

Comment: i've done that before but then the internal condition was not executing but now done it

Comment: thnx guys for always be here to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only restaurant names use below code.

```
dbReference = Database.database().reference()
dbReference?.child("Restaurants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            print("Restaurant Name:\(rest.key)")
        }

})
```

And to pass all data using StoryboardId  use below code.

```
dbReference = Database.database().reference()
dbReference?.child("Restaurants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            print("Restaurant Data:\(rest)")

        }

})
```

Put this in your 
And declare data variable in destinationController like below:

```
var data = [DataSnapshot]()
```

You have to performsegue from didselectRowAt like this.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

And you can pass the data of selected item from the below function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
let index = CategorytableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
let indexNumber = index?.row
print(indexNumber!)
let VC = segue.destination as! DestinationVC
VC.data = [rest] . //You can pass here entire data of selected row.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use below code to get parent node name.

```
 ref = Database.database().reference()

 ref?.child("Restaurants").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let rest = snapshot.value as? String
// snapshot.key is give you parent node name
        print(snapshot.key)
    }
})
```

Comment: Glad to hear brother! happy coding and complate your project ASAP

Comment: made my day thumbs up to you

Comment: `.childAdded` is not right way to get all the data. You will get data one by one also how would you know when its done?

Comment: Please guys,how do i get exactly same result with Javascript?